# check each variable of a column pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pivot table:

```
Type    Result
l   213
l   435
h   54
l   34
h   54
l   645
h   345
h   34
h   345
l   345
l   666
```

I want to calculate the `result` column depending on it's `type` colume 'l' or 'h':

```
for h, f(result);
for l, g(result);
```

Finally, append the calculation results as a new column in this pivot table.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You've not stated what the calculation is

Comment: @EdChum for example f(result) = result^2 +1. g(result) = result*2 +1

Comment: You can do `df.loc[df['Type'] == 'h','result'] = np.pow(df['result'], 2) + 1` and  `df.loc[df['Type'] == 'h', 'result'] = df['result'] * 2 + 1`

Comment: @EdChum I think I got your answer, but how can I add a calculation result at the same time? thanks

Comment: That should've worked

Comment: @EdChum Sorry, I just tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post raw data and code to reproduce your df and the errors from my code, thanks

Comment: @EdChum oh got u! need to add .item  df.loc[df['Type'] == 'h','result'] = np.pow(df['result']'.item', 2) + 1

Comment: Where does `.item` come from? is this a column?

Comment: @EdChum thanks in advance! df.loc[df['Type'] == 'h','result'] = np.pow(df['result']`.item`, 2) + 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103647/discussion-between-condo-programmer-and-edchum).

Comment: @EdChum Hey EdChum, you are right. Don't need `.item`, the code didn't work because I have a if syntax like: f(x) = 100, if result >200; f(x) = 1000, if result <200.